# VS Code background image not accepted

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have the following code in my `CSS` file that should allow me to set a `background-image` property and it's not working:

```
.landing-page-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(/images/adventure-calm-clouds-414171.jpeg);
```

The idea is that when I go inside the parenthesis and start typing with a "/", it finds the path to my folder within my project folder but still it does not apply the background image. What am I missing? Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried also with single quote and double quotes but still no success.

**EDIT2**

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want Visual Studio Code to auto-complete the path? You probably need an extension. Can you please edit the question and clarify what role VSCode plays?

Answer (score -1):

removed / at first inside background-image: url()

```
.landing-page-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("images/adventure-calm-clouds-414171.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Why removing `/` ? how do you know if `/` is not part of URL?

Comment: Thanks for new updated screen layout now I know. the issue as well as you already got a solution for question

Answer (score -1):

Well, apparently using two dots before the path did the trick. So the final value for `background-image` property is like this:

```
.landing-page-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/adventure-calm-clouds-414171.jpeg);
```

Comment: Those 2 dots in start allows you to get out of the current folder. In your case, it is very likely that your html file was placed in css folder while the image is in "images" folder. So to fetch an image from "images" folder you must first get out of the current css folder and then access image in the "images" folder.